# How to run my operator on a timer or continuously?

Tags: python, add-on, operator

I have a device connected to the computer over serial. I have managed to read the value from it using an operator executed by a button press, but now, I want my Blender plugin to poll for a value on an timed interval.

Modal technically works but it only runs when there's inputs present and it does so as fast as possible. So unless I constantly move the mouse, it won't run.

How can I get my operator to execute periodically? On a predefined time period?

Comment: I suggest the you tag @JacquesLuke because he made it possible for animation nodes to be executed always at intervals of a set minimum time difference.